# How to use the buttons to trigger Javascript Transform/Transition?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, triggers, transform

I want to make press the button to trigger a wave of animation, 
Use .water:hover event can be successfully implemented, 
but do not know how to Use the buttons to trigger, 
I Try to use the button to trigger class :focus event, but was unsuccessful ...

```
.water {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-image: url("waves.png");
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        transition: all 3s ease-out;
    }

.water:hover  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
                 transition: all 3s ease-out;
    }
```

Change the trigger type

```
.water {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-image: url("waves.png");
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
        transition: all 3s ease-out;
    }

.water:focus  {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
                 transition: all 3s ease-out;
    }
```

Approach to the button in html jQuery

```
  $(function() {            $('#digitButton1').click(function(event) {
                            $('.water').addClass('focus');
                        });
                    });
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.water').not($(this)).removeClass('focus');
                    });
```

How can I do?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a transition is defined in CSS it will apply to any changes.  This means that if it is changed through Javascript (or JQuery) it will still work so I think that adding

```css
.water {
    transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease-out;
}
```

to your CSS and

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#digitButton1').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.querySelector('.water').style.width = '500px';
        document.querySelector('.water').style.height = '500px';
    }
}
```

to your javascript should give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's trigger function to trigger different kind of events. Check this for reference api.jquery.com/trigger/

You can use something like

```
$('#digitButton1').click(function(event) {
                            $('.box').trigger('focus');
                        });
```